# Alternate row color not applied properly

Tags: css, jquery-ui, uitableview, jquery

Following is the jQuery search function i'm using,

```
$("#btnSearch").click(function () {
    debugger
    var assoid = $('#txtAssoID').val();
    var tassoid = $.trim(assoid);
    if ((tassoid == "") || (tassoid == "Ex: Associate Id1; Associate Id2; Associate Id3")) {
        alert("Please enter Associate ID");
        return false;
    } else if (tassoid != "") {

        for (var i = 0; i < tassoid.length; i++) {
            if (tassoid.charAt(i) == ':') {
                alert("colon should not be used");
                return false;
            }
        }
        var associateIDs = new Array();
        var array = tassoid.split(";");
        var array1 = tassoid.split(";").length;
        for (var k = 0; k < array1; k++) {
            var id = array[k];
            associateIDs[k] = id;
            if (k == 0) var associate = id;
            else var associate = associate + ',' + id;

            if (id.length != 6) {
                alert("Please enter 6 digit valid Associate ID");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    $.get("Search", {
        'AssoIdsForAccess': associate
    }, function (data) {
        $("#Search").html(data);
        $("#btnUpdate").removeAttr("disabled");
    })
});
```

while loading the webpage first time(html data displayed as a table) table row displayed with the background color but when i search an id second time the backgroung color is not applied which will be the location of that issue?

Comment: please post your css, html(_only the relevant part_) and the response data..

Comment: i'm using following jquery in search partialview,

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
 $(".tabble_assoc_srch tbody").find("tr:odd").css("background-color","#F2F1F7"); 
 $(".tabble_assoc_srch tbody").find("tr:even").css("background-color","#D0D1E3"); 
});

Comment: This Alternate row color is working first time loading the page.

Answer (score 0):

try this : live('click', function(){}) if you can Use jQuery 2.0 you have to use on('click', function(){})